# Xsane Plugin in Gimp can Preview an image, but can't open the scanner to scan it

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, gimp, epson

I have Lubuntu 20.04LTS and an Epson 4-in-1 XP-440 that's fairly vanilla and is supported.  All features were plug-and-play in 18.04LTS...worked out of the box like a charm.  I upgraded to 20.04LTS and now oddly, I can see the printer, I can PREVIEW the image (the darn scanner scans on command and pulls up a thumbnail), but no matter what I do (and I've tried a bunch of things!) I get a little chirp from the scanner, then a zip-zip sound, then a message "Failed to start scanner:  Invalid Argument."  I've installed the latest Epson imagescan driver, I've added myself to the "scanner" group (as per one suggestion out there), I've tried the different scanner options (some are http, others https...)  No dice so far.

When I run Xsane (it's version 0.999) in a terminal, I get the following:

```
Gdk-CRITICAL **: 21:22:54.466: IA__gdk_drawable_unref: assertion 'GDK_IS_DRAWABLE (drawable)' failed
```

Not being drawable sounds like it might be the issue but I've no idea how to fix it.

Any suggestions out there?  Thank you!

Comment: What is you version of XSane? Many changes to Gimp between 18.04 (Gimp 2.8) and 20.04 (Gimp 2.10)

Comment: It is Xsane 0.999.  I will edit the question to add that.  Thank you!